# Stuck on ez publish setup wizard

Tags: content-management-system, ezpublish

I'm installing ez publish 5 on a linux machine, but when I got to the web based setup wizard, I got stuck on the first page. Clicking on `Next >` doesn't do nothing but refresh the page.
Has anyone gone through this?

Aditional info: Clicking on the `Finetune` doesn't work either, and I've already downloaded another version of ez publish and the same problem appears.
[image: I got stuck here!]

Comment: What is your apache setup? I have experienced this bug in the past and I was able to fix it by adjusting my apache configuration.

Comment: have you tried permissions on your filesystem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current workaround is to use a VirtualHost based setup for your web server. Taking Apache as an example, you can find a ready-made virtual host conf here:
https://confluence.ez.no/display/EZP/Virtual+host+setup

Cheers,